# Refer #element and change its attribute dyanmically of a component from template of current component ( Angular 2 )

Tags: angular, typescript

Framework : **Angular 2 Typescript**

Component to Refer **ng2-select**

**Template :**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let **i=index**;>
<ng-select [items]="myItems" #element**{{i}}**><ng-select>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

If it was a single element

```
@ViewChild('element') select:SelectComponent;
```

and later

this.select.active=[{ id: 0, text: 'Africa' }]    //Works But i want to use it like function below

**But I want**

*In a function block i want to refer selected dynamic #element**No** and alter a value*
eg

```
myFunction(i:number){
//Change active attribute of the corresponding element dynamically referenced from DOM using View Child / Renderer / Element Ref or anything that might help
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Actually, Problem is is not to set the attribute..

But dynamically accessing the element from DOM

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly you want to change? Is it `<option>` tag? Or do you have multiple `<ng-select>` in your directive and you want to change (e.g. disable) one of them? Also please explain what exactly triggers that change? Is it button, ajax, select specific option?

Comment: I want to change active attribute that belongs to ng2-select component, whose selector and use is <ng-select #element{{Number}}>

and i want to refer it dynamically in my TS and change use it like,

myReferenceOf( #element3 / #element4 ).active=My Value..

Using @ViewChild / Renderer / ElementRef

Answer (score 0):

**update**

`@ViewChild()` doesn't support dynamic parameters. You can inject

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}
```

and then use

```
myFunction(i:number) {
  this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('[' + i ']');
}
```

Hint: Attribute names can't start with a number AFAIR.

**original**

```
myFunction(i:number) {
  this.select.setAttribute('id', i);
  this.select.setAttribute('text', 'Aftrika');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,

But problem is not setting the attribute but dynamically accessing it from the DOM

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamically accessing it from the DOM"?

Comment: Using @ViewChild i can refer to element, and change its corresponding value..

Like @ViewChild('#myElementIdInDom')

I want to do it dynamically because i cant pre declare the values that might come from ngFor

Comment: `@ViewChild()` doesn't support dynamic parameters. You can inject `elRef:ElementRef` and then use `this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('[' + i ']')` or similar

Comment: does this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#element'+i) allow me to use it to set attribute corresponding to the component?

because from <ng-select #element1> finally what i want to do is myReference.active="My Value" i.e. active attribute which belongs to that component..

Comment: So you want to pass a value to an input? " set attribute of corresponding to the component" is misleading. Only DOM elements have attributes. Components have inputs. If the value is a string it should work (not sure though). If you want to pass other values, you definitely can't use this approach. You can use `@ViewChildren(SelectComponent) selects:QueryList<SelectComponent>;` and then filter `this.selects` for the one component instance you want to access and then set a property of the component.

Comment: Sure.. Thanks for the knowledge. When i try to use elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#element').active=myValue,

It doesnt detect the input and gives me error saying..

Cannot set Property active of null

Comment: Use `setAttribute()` as shown in my original answer.

Comment: Hey Seriously thanks for your time..
I know this is silly but could u tell me if i am supposed to pass a hash or not in querySelector like ('#country') or ('country') .. Also an example of html template would help a lot..

Reason : Its again saying - Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: `'#country'` selects `<some-element id="country"></some-element>` while `'country'` selects `<country></country>`. Sorry, for me it's still too vague what you actually try to accomplish for me to be able to make a more concrete example.

Comment: for now how i used it is 
<ng-select #country >

and referenced to it as @ViewChild('country') xyz:SelectComponent;

and later xyz.active=myValue

Comment: You can't use `country` from `<ng-select #country >` in `querySelector`. You need to change it to `<ng-select id="c1">` and then use `querySelector('#c1')` the `#` in `querySelector` and in `<ng-select #country>` are entirely unrelated. The former is a CSS element id selector, the later is an Angular2 template variable. You can't use template variables with `querySelector`

Comment: Ok Let me try it with id="country", meanwhile, is there any way to refer the angular 2 template variable and change the same?

Comment: You can't change angular2 template variables. You can add them statically to a components template but not dynamically and not change them in any way. The only ways to refer to them is using `@ViewChild[ren](...)` `@ContentChild[ren](...)` and by name from within the same template loke `<button (click)="country.setAttribute('active', false)"`

Comment: Ok, but is there no way to change the dynamically added angular template variable ids?

Comment: Also, now it doesnt give me errors, But it doesnt change my select box text as required.. :(
   
i did <ng-select id="country">

and in ts,   elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#country').setAttribute('active','myValue');

Comment: What is `<ng-select>`? Is that your own component or 3rd party?

Comment: a third party component ng2-select that gives me searchable selectBox.
For a better idea

https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/

Comment: `active` expects an array, not a string. You can't use `setAttribute`. Use instead the `@ViewChildren()` approach mentioned above.

Comment: ViewChildren, How can i use to dynamic angular template element ids?
wait..      
<ng-select id='country'  #country [items]="countries"></ng-select>

I want to refer it dynamically in a function and change it say

changeCountry(myArrayValue){ countryReference.active=myArrayValue }

problem is i want to declare it inside this function block and not globally inside my current component class.

because problem is not to set this #country but 

<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
<ngselect #itemNumber{{ i }}   > </ng-select>
</div>

Comment: and i want to refer that $itemNumber3 say and change it

Comment: Hey Gunter. My problem still remains floating. Anycase, Thanks for your time bro.